# Making an altcoin (for fun, not to use), and after finding MerkleRoot and genesis block, I still get errors

Tags: error, genesis-block

I'm making a PoW/PoS hybrid coin for fun (nobody will actually use it).  I already found the Merkle root and mined the genesis block and got the nonce and things like that.  I inserted them into the correct places (or so I thought) in main.cpp and main.h.  I also deleted the checkpoints from the coin I cloned from.  I now get this error:

> bool LoadBlockIndex(bool): Assertion `block.GetHash() == hashGenesisBlock' failed.

What should I do?  It does not make sense to me, as this error normally means that there is trouble related to mining the genesis block.  If anybody wants to see the source code, it's at GitHub:  https://github.com/hale6666/kaluricoin

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you'll get anyone here helping. Best to try BCT